# "Welcome to BioFarm, a leading Finnish innovative biotech company" - does "leading" combine well with "innovative"?

Tags: adjectives, word-order

Let's say that we have a website with this sentence on its intro page:

> Welcome to BioFarm, a **leading** Finnish **innovative** biotech company

Does the word **leading** combine well with **innovative**, or is it better to use either **leading** or **innovative**?

I feel like the words somehow overlap in meaning. They both indicate that the company is "cool".

I would strike out "innovative" and maybe try to use this word (if requested by the customer) in some other way.

> Welcome to BioFarm, a leading Finnish biotech company (engaged in innovative research?)

Comment: I would write "Welcome to BioFarm, a leading innovative Finnish biotech company". I don't see any overlap in the meanings of the modifiers. "cool" would be a vague description in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> leading

goes well with

> innovative

it implies the reason the company is a *leading* company is because it is *innovative*.